# Getting all LEDs in /sys/class/leds

Tags: wireless, drivers, 15.10, bluetooth, ralink

I want to be able to control the two dual (orange/white) LEDs on my HP Probook 4540s laptop. However, I don't see them in the list:

```
/sys/class/leds/hp::hddprotect
/sys/class/leds/input3::capslock
/sys/class/leds/input3::numlock
/sys/class/leds/input3::scrolllock
/sys/class/leds/mmc0::
/sys/class/leds/rt2800pci-phy0::assoc
/sys/class/leds/rt2800pci-phy0::quality
/sys/class/leds/rt2800pci-phy0::radio
```

The last three items are obviously referring to the Ralink WiFi/BT card, but changing the brightness for any of them doesn't affect the LEDs (works fine for others).

My question is **where do those entries in /sys/ come from? Is it possible to add my own? Any (HP specific?) system drivers that enable this?**

The only way I've seen the LED change colors is when activating both Wifi and Bluetooth, but that only worked on a specific set of drivers and/or under specific ACPI setting (can't remember which, but it caused some of the key features not to work, so I gave up on using Bluetooth at all).

Not sure if it has to do something with the generic drivers I'm using:

```
GENERAL.PRODUCT:  RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe (Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter)
GENERAL.DRIVER:   rt2800pci
```

Comment: You should add the purpose of the dual-color LEDs you're describing.

Comment: `/sys` is an interface to the kernel. You'll probably have to do kernel module programming to add to it, which would be too broad and off-topic for us.

Comment: @ByteCommander I'm not sure about it, they are next to Open Browser and WLAN Switch buttons and the only time I've seen the right one switch to white is when I had both the Wifi and Bluetooth working (gave up on BT afterwards as stated in the question).

Comment: @muru that's helpful, thank you. Do you know if there's a way to get the full LED list by changing certain system drivers?

Comment: Dunno. Maybe you can make some sense of http://derekmolloy.ie/kernel-gpio-programming-buttons-and-leds/ and https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/leds/leds-class.txt

Comment: Thanks, I've read both those articles earlier, but was really hoping I won't have to do HP's work. :)

Answer (score 2):

These commands worked for my **HP Pavilion g7 2269wm** running **elementary OS freya** (based on Ubuntu 14.04).

#### Make LED orange

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/hp::hddprotect/brightness
```

#### Make LED white (default)

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/hp::hddprotect/brightness
```

After running the first command your LED should turn **orange** even when there is no disk activity and becomes a **mix of white and orange** with disk activity.

The second command will make it **white** again and turn off when no disk activty like default.

> This file is used by the [lis3lv02d](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/misc-devices/lis3lv02d) kernel driver to change the color when the
>   laptop is dropped while also parking the hard drive.

Comment: That one works fine - I wrote: `"The last three items are obviously referring to the Ralink WiFi/BT card, but changing the brightness for any of them doesn't affect the LEDs (works fine for others)."` I'm curious about getting the WiFi LED working. It's also a dual-color LED. Using HP Probook 4540s. This is the LED: http://www.withsteps.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/wireless-led-problem-in-hp-laptop-always-white-even-with-airplane-mode-on.png

Comment: I can't test that one since recently the WiFi LED on my keyboard burned.And yours isn't on the keyboard so I think it is different

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what's controlling it. I've seen it change the color with specific drivers and BT/WiFi setup, so it's doable, but I have no idea why it's not responding to the standard brightness parameters.

Comment: This may help http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/platform/x86/hp-wmi.c

Comment: Thank you, by skimming through the code I've seen the wifi handler only managing/setting up the `rfkill` states, nothing related to controlling the LEDs. I'll give it a better look later.